# restart timers for one operation in java

Tags: java, timer, timertask

I have one button include timer, but when I clicked the button again, same timer start counting twice.  I want to stop the counter every time and restart it. how can I do it?

```
    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        int cnt=0;
        Timer timer=new Timer();
        TimerTask task=new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                cnt++;
                System.out.println("task: "+cnt);  
            }
         };
         timer.schedule(task, 0, 3000);
    }
```

when I clicked the button again, it calls system out twice.

Comment: can you add some code to your question?

Comment: Yes exactly @pfaehlfd

Answer (score 0):

By calling Timer timer = new Timer(); inside handleButtonAction you create a new Timer with every click.

You have to declare the Timer outside the method, then you can restart it by clicking the button like:

```
Timer timer;
private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
    int cnt=0;
    timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            cnt++;
            System.out.println("task: "+cnt);  
        }
     };
     timer.schedule(task, 0, 3000);
}
```

This way you always restart the same timer.

Comment: I am sorry but it continues double counting.